# How do I get <%= Html.Encode(item.name) %> in the title and head of page elements

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, title, head

How do I get <%= Html.Encode(item.name) %> in the title and head of page elements

I am wanting to use this the content place holder - title content, and main content. However each time I try to add these in the those elements i get an error basically saying this not allowed.

```
<h2>Performances for :<%= Html.Encode(item.venue) %></h2>
```

this is what I have been doing but it wont work

can somebody please help with my query, thanks.

Comment: can we see all or part of your master page / view?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `runat="server"` attribute from your `<head>` tag. It's legacy left from the good ol' days of WebForms which has no any viable meaning in MVC that someone forgot to remove from the default template.

Also if the `item` variable is not available in the masterpage you could use a content placeholder which will be redefined in each view if this variable is part of a view model which is only available in views.

Comment: this doesnt work, I am still getting an error. i have a strongly typed view on the page I would like to use it on, is this affecting it?

Comment: @MarkT, what error are you getting more precisely? Have you defined the `item` variable that you are trying to use? You could use a content placeholder which will be redefined in each view if this variable is part of a view model which is only available in views.

Comment: I keep getting this error - Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'item' does not exist in the current context. Im trying to use information from a database that is already on the rendered page

Comment: @MarkT, then you could use a ContentPlaceholder which you will override in the view.

Comment: How would I go about overriding the contentplaceholder??

Comment: @MarkT, the same way you do with the MainContent place holder: `<asp:Content ID="Title" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">Performances for :<%= Html.Encode(Model.venue) %></asp:Content>` where `TitleContent` is the name of the placeholder you used in the master page.

Comment: @Trev, can we please see more of your view?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try it without putting `<h2>` tags into the `<title>` section of the page.

Comment: Perhaps slightly harsh, but your answer doesn't provide any information or help towards a solution.